# How to set gradient color with angle

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient

I want to set gradient on my button, i have to set simple linear gradient(without angle) with two color, but i don't know how to set angle value on gradient

Angle:- 61

below image define psd gradient overlay effect

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at `startPoint` and `endPoint` of `CAGradientLayer` to set an angle (it set the "line", but that could be translated from an angle).

Comment: How can i calculate start point and end point based on angle value, because in feature if angle value will be changed. If u know any formula to calculate start point and end point based on angle value than please let me know @Larme

Comment: That's simple math. not really programming

Comment: ya, but which formula i can use for this, if you have than let me know @Larme

Answer (score 2):

Try it, maybe it will help

- (CAGradientLayer *)gradientLayerWithColors:(NSArray *)colors angle:(CGFloat)angle {

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
layer.colors = colors;

CGFloat x = angle / 360.f;

CGFloat a = pow(sin((2*M_PI*((x+0.75)/2))),2);
CGFloat b = pow(sin((2*M_PI*((x+0.0)/2))),2);
CGFloat c = pow(sin((2*M_PI*((x+0.25)/2))),2);
CGFloat d = pow(sin((2*M_PI*((x+0.5)/2))),2);

layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(a, b);
layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(c, d);
return layer;
```

}

Comment: I already tried this solution but doesn't set proper gradient @Eugene Sokolenko

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly modified code generated by [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) that solves just this problem:

```
UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: self.view.bounds];
UIBezierPath* rectangleRotatedPath = [rectanglePath copy];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(yourAngleInRadians);
[rectangleRotatedPath applyTransform: transform];
CGRect rectangleBounds = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(rectangleRotatedPath.CGPath);
transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(transform);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangleBounds), CGRectGetMidY(rectangleBounds)), transform);
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectangleBounds), CGRectGetMidY(rectangleBounds)), transform);
```

The code takes your initial rectangle (black rectangle) and angle (shown as black line), rotates the rectangle (you'll get blue rectangle), then finds bounding box of the rotated rectangle (red rectangle). Takes endpoints on the bounds (red dots) and transforms (rotates) them back using invert transform (blue dots).

[image: Finding endpoints]

Other solution might be finding intersection of your rectangle and a line defined by the angle.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this solution doesn't work for me @mato

Answer (score 0):

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientMask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, myView.bounds.size.width, myView.bounds.size.height);

gradientMask.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
gradientMask.locations = @[@0.0, @0.10, @0.60, @1.0];

[myView.layer insertSublayer:gradientMask atIndex:0];
```

adjust location value and frame size accordingly.

Comment: I know that but how can i calculate start point and end point based on angle value. If you have any formula for this than please let me know @kaushal